# Create a vector of user defined type that has uniform random distribution as private member with reproducible results

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, random, shared-ptr

Hard to resume in the title. I have got the following situation:

```
#include <random>

class classRng{

public:

    classRng(){
    }
    classRng(int aSeed){
        Rng.seed(aSeed);
    }

    void setSeed(int seed){
        Rng.seed(seed);
    }

    std::vector<int>& getResults(){
        return extractedNum;
    }

    void run(int low, int up);

private:

    std::vector<int> extractedNum;

    mutable std::mt19937 Rng;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> randomUniformGenerator;


};

void classRng::run(int low,int up){

    decltype(randomUniformGenerator.param()) range(low, up);
    randomUniformGenerator.param(range);
    extractedNum.clear();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        extractedNum.push_back(randomUniformGenerator(Rng));
    }

}
```

This class extracts numbers from a distribution initiliazed with a seed for reproducibility. I want to underline that feed the RNG with a fixed and static seed is in my case mandatory in order to reproduce results.

Another class, say `targetClass`  is parameterized with `classRng` in this way:

```
template<class stochaticClass>
class targetClass{

public:

    targetClass(){}
    targetClass(stochaticClass _extr){
        extr=_extr;
    }

    void foo();

    stochaticClass& stochasticClassAccess(){
        return extr;
    }

private:

    stochaticClass extr;
    std::vector<int> storedResults;

};

template<class stochasticClass>
void targetClass<stochasticClass>::foo(){

    extr.run(1,30);
    storedResults = extr.getResults();

}
```

I want then create a vector of `targetClass` objects whose class method `foo()` produces different results. In the main() function I proceed as follow:

```
#include "classRng.cpp"
#include "targetClass.cpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int N=10;

    typedef targetClass<classRng> targetType;

    std::vector<targetType> objects(N);
    int seed=0;
    classRng instatiatedObj(seed);

    for(int i=0;i < N; i++){
        targetType thisObject(instatiatedObj);
        objects[i]=thisObject;
        objects[i].foo();
    }

}
```

I would like to achieve the situation where each object in the vector produces different results ( store different results in `storedResults`) but produce the very same results with another run of the executable. 
I show my last approach after try to firstly set with a setter function the classRng and later I tried simply to build each `targetClass` with the default constructor without explicitly use the custom constructor with `classRng instatiatedObj` as argument.

**Update**

I managed the problem by using pointers:

```
main(){
...
    classRng* pointer2clrng=nullptr;
    pointer2clrng=&instatiatedObj;
...
}

class targetClass{

...

public:
    targetClass(){}
    targetClass(stochaticClass* _extr){
       extr=&_extr;
       }

...

private:
    stochaticClass* extr;

...

}
```

This seems ok but I wonder if it worth use smart pointer or even look for methods avoiding pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in storing a std::uniform_int_distribution in classRng. Also Rng doesn't need to be mutable. classRng can thus be

```
#include <random>

class classRng{
public:
    classRng(){
    }

    classRng(int aSeed) :
        Rng{ aSeed }
    {}

    void setSeed(int seed){
        Rng.seed(seed);
    }

    std::vector<int>& getResults(){
        return extractedNum;
    }

    void run(int low, int up);

private:

    std::vector<int> extractedNum;

    std::mt19937 Rng;
};

void classRng::run(int low,int up){
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> randomUniformGenerator{ low, up };
    extractedNum.clear();

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        extractedNum.push_back(randomUniformGenerator(Rng));
    }
}
```

The problem is that you need to pass a classRng seeded with a different value to each object in your vector.

```
#include "classRng.h"
#include "targetClass.h"
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N=10;
    typedef targetClass<classRng> targetType;

    std::vector<targetType> objects(N);
    std::minstd_rand seedGenerator{0};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution;

    for(int i=0;i < N; i++){
        objects[i] = targetType{classRng{ distribution(seedGenerator) }};
        objects[i].foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Seed with different values is a solution. But why are they generating the same results if the class is constructed with the same object that has the same distribution? I mean, the distribution in `classRNG` should change its state when `foo()` is called by `objects[i]`. What am I intrepreting wrong?